# Using crontab to make a influxdb backup every week

Tags: cron, influxdb

So I'm wondering how can I make a cron job to make influxdb backup every friday at midnigth. In github is an sh file that makes the backup job, here is the link: [InfluxDB Backup-Restore](https://github.com/eckardt/influxdb-backup.sh)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I use this repo https://github.com/eckardt/influxdb-backup.sh and make the crontab job to make the periodic backup.

Comment: This script works against very old versions of InfluxDB. It does not work for any 0.9.x version.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but for now we don't going to upgrade frome version 0.8.4

Answer (score 1):

Influxdb supports backup and restore, documentation available [here](https://influxdb.com/docs/v0.9/concepts/backup_and_restore.html) 
Should be straight forward to add a crontab for it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but for now we don't going to upgrade frome version 0.8.4.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a jenkins job is also an option. Easy and stable.